# Debugging Event Grid posts

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

I've recently started using Event Grid for some backend integrations and have run into a situation where some of the Topic pushes are not being received by the subscriber.

Is it possible to log/debug the Event topic pushes that are inbound so I can see examine where the issue is (e.g. view the `eventtype` field). I can see via metrics that there is a delta between published events and the number which are delivered which means the filter I have in place in the subscriber is working. But I can't tell what the publisher is actually sending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a catch all (no filters) subscription on your topic which could log all events for debugging.

With the logged events, you could check & confirm if the filters you have set on the other subscription are incorrect (or if the data coming is in incorrect).

Also, in case you have delivery failures, then you can setup [diagnostic logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/enable-diagnostic-logs-topic) and a [dead-letter location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/manage-event-delivery#set-dead-letter-location) for such events.